# Does vue.extend has lifecycle?

Tags: vue.js

Can I use [Instanec Lifecycle Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) within `Vue.extend`? I am trying to catch the event, which I am emitting using `eventHub.$emit`, so I thought to put `eventHub.$on` inside `created` but it never really catches emitted, so I am not sure if using `eventHub.$on` inside `Vue.extend` is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every Vue component has all the lifecycle methods. The **root instance** is just a special case of general Vue component with few additional methods.

Comment: When you say "every Vue component" does it mean that `Vue.extend` counts as component also?
And will it accept events emitted through `eventHub.$emit`?

Comment: @niksrb, Yes indeed. That is the case. `Vue.extend`, `Vue.component()` and others are all same.